# Responsive iFrame or alternative solution

Tags: iframe, responsive-design

I would like to create a responsive iframe for the map on this webpage http://www.kitebom.com.au/.

Answer (score 1):

It's responsive and it's [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), btw I didn't see any `iframes` in that website example you posted. `Iframes` are not for the faint of heart, I strongly advise against it. That site actually used a [**map**][1] for the map and it's coordinates, that would be harder to do than an iframe.

### CSS

```
    html { color: #000; font: 600 16px/1.45 Arial; }

    *, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; list-style: none; text-decoration: none; }

    body { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }

    #flexMain { display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center; align-items: stretch; align-content: stretch; border: 2px solid blue; width: 100%; height: 100%; }

    #flexMap { display: inline-block; flex: 0 0 80%; width: 40em; height: 100%; background: yellow; }

    #flexNav { display: inline-block; flex: 0 0 20%; width: 10em; height: 100%; background: green; }

    .flexible * { text-align: center; border: 10px solid red; }
```

### HTML

```
  <main id="flexMain" class="flexible">
    <nav id="flexNav" class="flexible">
      NAV
    </nav>
    <section id="flexMap" class="flexible">
      MAP
   </section>
 </main>
```

## UPDATE

### HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>iframe</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
<nav>&nbsp;</nav>
</header>
<main>
<section>
<h1>TITLE</h1>
<h2>TOPIC</h2>
<h3>SUB-TOPIC</h3>
<p><span ="big">CONTENT</span></p>
</section>
<section>
<h3>MAP</h3>
<figure>
<figcaption>MAP TITLE</figcaption>
<iframe src="http://www.kitebom.com.au/" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="overflow: auto; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;" height="60vh" width="100vw" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
</figure>
<p><span ="big">CONTENT</span></p>
</section>
</main>
<footer>
<aside>&nbsp;</aside>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The above link goes to the jsFiddle demo, because the iframed site is insecure, it takes jsFiddle a while to load, but eventually it does.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I explained myself well... I don't own kitebom.com.au, I would just like to display their wind map on my responsive website.

Comment: I gathered that, sir. What you can do is use the responsive flexbox layout I gave you as a template. Even though it's only two boxes, if you put more flex items in, it'll still be 100% responsive (as long as you follow the pattern and test the layout first.) Atm you could start placing a <map> element into the map area, then a menu in the nav area.

Comment: Oh, may bad, sorry. Ok, then here you go:                                       <iframe src="http://www.kitebom.com.au/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;" height="100%" width="100%" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: This site strips the protocol from iframe markup, so the attribute `src` is actually `https://www.kitebom.com.au/`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: the map is an image so you can just use it without any iframe as long as you put the absolute path with the domain and protocol in your `img` `src`.

`<img src="http://www.kitebom.com.au/images/graphs/map-melbourne.png?1441817570">`

http://www.kitebom.com.au/images/graphs/map-melbourne.png?1441817570